# Type of variable that contains type, not instance

Tags: typescript

I work with sequalize models. They are classes. When I register them some data is attached to them. So I need store them. I store them in a list. But when I retrieve a model to a variable, a little confuse appears. What does the variable have to have a type to store the type?

Comment: I think you will find better responses if you post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you need because you have not posted any code demonstrating your issue.  It's quite possible that all you need is to use the `typeof` [type query](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.8.10) on your class constructor:

```
class Foo { ... }
class Bar { ... }
class Baz { ... }
var instances: (Foo | Bar | Baz)[] = [new Foo(), new Baz(), new Foo()];
var classes: (typeof Foo | typeof Bar | typeof Baz)[] = [Foo, Baz, Foo];
```

Or maybe you want to specify a constructor generically, which you can do as follows:

```
type Constructor<T = {}> = {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
  readonly prototype: T;
}
var classes: (Constructor<Foo|Bar|Baz>)[] = [Foo, Baz, Foo];
```

I hope that helps.  If you need more, please add more details to your question.  Good luck!